# How can I override the title of an X11 window running across an SSH tunnel?

Tags: xorg, firefox, ssh, window-manager, x11-forwarding

I am SSH'ing into a server which has a copy of Firefox installed on it that I need to run.

I can SSH in and run Firefox, and it will run remotely as expected.

However, I need to frequently have two Firefoxes open from two different servers. Identifying which one is which at a glance is a little tricky.

I can easily script the opening of each remote Firefox, but I'd like to add to that script a mechanism that gets the newly created window and overrides the title to be "SERVER_XYZ". Or prepends it. Or something.

I'd love it to be automatic (scriptable) and general (not Firefox-specific) if it is possible. But if not, manual would be OK.

As well, I tried xdotool (`xdotool search --class Firefox set_window --name "Server"`) but that wouldn't override the title of the Firefox window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for Firefox, there are add-ons that should be able to help you, e.g., [firetitle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firetitle/). Install and configure it on the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like there's no generic alternative at this point. Appreciate the reply!